# Use aws-encryption-sdk to decrypt with context in on-prem environment

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, amazon-kms

I want to consume encrypted messages using the aws_encryption_sdk python module. The messages are encrypted by another team using a context.

The reason to use aws_encryption_sdk is to reduce the cost by reducing the number of KMS sessions whenever we call the boto3 kms client decrypt  function. However, I seem to be stuck and confused as I can't find where I can use that when calling the decrypt function for the **EncryptionSDKClient**

My code looks something like this:

```
client = aws_encryption_sdk.EncryptionSDKClient()

## try to set the botocore session for Master Key Provider
kms_kwargs= dict(key_ids=data['keyId'])
key_provider = aws_encryption_sdk.StrictAwsKmsMasterKeyProvider(**kms_kwargs)

MAX_ENTRY_AGE_SECONDS = 600.0
MAX_ENTRY_MESSAGES = 10
MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 10


cache = aws_encryption_sdk.LocalCryptoMaterialsCache(MAX_CACHE_SIZE)

caching_cmm = CachingCryptoMaterialsManager(
    master_key_provider=key_provider,
    cache=cache,
    max_age=MAX_ENTRY_AGE_SECONDS,
    max_messages_encrypted=MAX_ENTRY_MESSAGES
)

cycled_plaintext, decrypted_header = client.decrypt(source=base64.b64decode(data["encryptedData"]), key_provider=key_provider)
```

Please note that I need to cache the data key in on-premise environment.

Answer (score 1):

From the [AWS Developer Guide on KMS Encryption SDK page, encryption context section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/concepts.html#encryption-context):

> To decrypt the data, you pass in the encrypted message. Because the AWS Encryption SDK can extract the encryption context from the encrypted message header, you are not required to provide the encryption context separately. However, the encryption context can help you to confirm that you are decrypting the correct encrypted message.

There is also a few examples of code verifying the encryption contexts that you may find useful [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/python-example-code.html).